# Java Graphics only overlaying new shapes?

Tags: java, linux, swing

I'm working on a program that displays an animation using the MVC architecture. The model contains shapes and tells them to mutate themselves. The view in question is a class that extends JPanel. It accepts the shapes from the controller and places them on the Graphics object in `paintComponent`. The controller has a while loop in its `run` method that tells the model to mutate all of the shapes, pushes those shapes to the view, and then sleeps the thread for a certain amount of time.

However, the problem I'm running into is this: the Graphics object seems to be simply overlaying the new shapes for every `paintComponent` call, so that you can see the trail of the shapes throughout the whole run of the program. This is only a problem when the view extends JPanel (program ran fine for the previous implementation, which was a JFrame that had an anonymous JPanel class), and only seems to be a problem on my Linux machine (my project partner uses a macbook -- tagging `Linux` since it could be tied to Linux platform). Also, I've tried it with Oracle jdk8, open-jdk8, and open-jdk10.

I'm sure it's just a bug in my code, since other programs work. Could it be a bug that the Linux jdk finds but not macOS?

I'm going to do my best to do pseudo code so I don't get docked for plagiarism

current code:

```
public class MyVisualView extends JPanel implements MyViews {
  // store my shapes with name shapes
  public MyVisualView() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    frame.getContentPane().add(this);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    // tried these individually -- didn't work
    this.setOpaque(true);
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  }

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    for (all of my shapes) {
      g.setColor(shape color);
      if (oval) g.fillOval(...);
      else g.fillRect(...);
    }
  }
}
```

previous code, which worked:

```
public class MyVisualView extends JFrame implements MyViews {
  public void run() {
    shapes = getShapes();

    JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
      @Override
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // same paintComponent as above
      }
    };

    while (true) {
      panel.repaint();
      // wait for a certain amount of time
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: Solved it by repainting the JFrame instead of the JPanel

Comment: `Edit: Solved it by repainting the JFrame instead of the JPanel` - wrong solution.

Answer (score 0):

> However, the problem I'm running into is this: the Graphics object seems to be simply overlaying the new shapes for every paintComponent call

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  for (all of my shapes) {
```

The code should be:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  for (all of my shapes) {
```

You need to invoke the default painting of the panel to clear the background first before repainting all your shapes.

Also:

```
while (true) {
  panel.repaint();
```

Don't use a while (true) loop for animation. Instead you should be using a Swing Timer to schedule the animation.

Take a look at the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are sections on:

1. `Custom Painting` - (ie. you should also be overriding the `getPreferredSize()` method)
2. `How to Use Swing Timer`

to get you started with the basics of each of these functions of Swing.